# References in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Coming from Web development background, I need some help understanding some of the basic syntax used in Android Applications' Java development aspects:

Context for these questions is the Development Training in development.android.com

1) How do the values "@string" , "@style" , "@drawable" reference to a directory on the project without explicitly given the exact path and exact folder name (drawable-hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi folders etc , strings.xml and styles.xml ) ?

2) According to the tutorial when I want to give a new ID resource definition I use "@+id/_" for that, is the action done behind the scene to add this as a temporary resource to the collection of id's used during runtime? would it be the same for a string or a style for example: "@+string/"? I'm asking because I know that the "@string/*_*" references to the "strings.xml" file but there is no "id.xml" file for id resources.

3) For the action bar the tutorial calls to use the themes directory from the Android Support class now I'm not sure how to call for them, mostly because they're in different Project files (the Android Support class is in appcompat_v7) and the tutorial just says to use "@style/Theme.AppCompat" when I don't have a resource called "Theme.AppCompact" in my "styles.xml" resource file.

Really frustraiting for me... would appreciate help on these!

Comment: Back to the documentation. All this is explained there... and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Android tool chain contains a special compiler called AAPT, the Android Asset Packaging tool.  It knows about certain blessed folders: `res/values`, `res/drawables`, and so on.  It actually even parses the folder names to build multiple versions of resources (`res/drawables-hdpi`, etc.).  AAPT produces two artifacts: one is the bundled resources that go into the APK, the other is a Java source file, for a class called `R`.  If you include the `R` class (eclipse puts it in the `gen` directory) as source for your application, you can refer to the resources directly from your Java code.
2. Yes.  You have that exactly right.  The value of an ID is interesting only in that it is different from other ids: it is unique.  AAPT can do that for you.  @+string/foo would work fine, if you wanted a string that contained a random-ish numeric value.  [Actually, AAPT appears to have checks, now, that won't allow it.  The point is still valid]
3. Themes and Styles are a pretty complex topics.  The documentation is sparse but getting better.  It's really out of scope for SO.